# Roots of factorization with expressions for constants

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

When faced with the factorization $$(\alpha - 1 -\lambda)(\mu - 1 -\lambda)=0$$ the roots of $\lambda$ can simply be said to be $\alpha - 1$ and $\mu - 1$. Why is that answer different to the following working?
$$\begin{align*} \alpha\mu - \alpha - \alpha\lambda - \mu +1 + 2\lambda - \lambda\mu + \lambda^2 &=0 \\
\lambda^2 + (2-\alpha - \mu) \lambda + \alpha\mu - \alpha - \mu + 1 &=0
\end{align*}$$
$$\begin{align*}
\lambda &= \frac{\alpha + \mu - 2 \pm\sqrt{(2-\alpha-\mu)^2 - 4(\alpha\mu - \alpha -\mu + 1)}}2 \\
 &= \frac{\alpha + \mu - 2 \pm\sqrt{4 - 4\alpha -4\mu + \alpha^2 + 2\alpha\mu + \mu^2 - 4(\alpha\mu - \alpha -\mu + 1)}}2 \\
  &= \frac{\alpha + \mu - 2 \pm\sqrt{\alpha^2 - 2\alpha\mu + \mu^2}}2 \\
  &= \frac{\alpha + \mu - 2 \pm\sqrt{(\alpha - \mu)^2}}2\\
  &= \frac{-\alpha + 3\mu }2\qquad\text{or}\qquad \frac {3\alpha - \mu}2
\end{align*}$$

Comment: $(2-\alpha-\mu)^2=4-4(\alpha-\mu)+(\alpha-\mu)^2=4-4(\alpha-\mu)+\alpha^2-2\alpha\mu +\mu^2$, it is the sign in $\alpha\mu$

Comment: The problem is that the last line of your work, contains error

Comment: it seems you confused $2\pm\sqrt{(\alpha-\mu)^2}$ with $2\times\sqrt{(\alpha-\mu)^2}$, taking $\pm$ for a multiplicative sign, this explain the disappearing of constant term $-1$ and the factors $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{\alpha+\mu-2\pm\sqrt{(\alpha-\mu)^2}}{2}=\frac{\alpha+\mu-2\pm(\alpha-\mu)}{2}\\ \implies\lambda_1=\frac{2\alpha-2}2=\alpha-1\\ 
\implies\lambda_2=\frac{2\mu-2}2=\mu-1$$
What seems to be the problem?  I cannot be sure how you ended up with the solutions that you did.

Comment: Oh, I was _multiplying_ 2 with $(\alpha - \mu)$. Thanks!